# How can I writeStream a csv file to console as sink when a new row is added?

Tags: csv, row, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to read csv file every 5 minutes and output any new rows that were added less than 5 minutes ago to another csv file. I think a good stepping stone is to readStream a csv file and writeStream to console to print out the file contents whenever I manually append a new row of data into the csv file. The issue is that console only prints when I insert an entirely new csv file into the directory.

How can I do print whenever I new row is added to the csv file?

Here is my directory layout:

- stream_script2.py (code below)
- csv_files

  - unit_testing.csv

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import (  
    StringType,
    IntegerType,
    StructType,
    StructField,
    TimestampType,
    BooleanType,
    DateType,
)

# Create SparkSession
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder.appName("streaming")
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()
)

# Made Schema
schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("Drug_Name", StringType(), True),
        StructField("Count", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField("Faulty", BooleanType(), True),
    ]
)
# Read Stream
df = (
    spark.readStream.option("sep", ";")
    .schema(schema)
    .format("csv")
    .load("csv_files/unit_testing*.csv")
)

# Write Stream
query = df.writeStream
    .format("console")
    .outputMode("append")
    .queryName("test1")
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()

# Ctrl-C to stop stream
```

Answer (score 0):

I am almost certain Spark structured streaming does not directly support functionality to notify me if new rows have been added. Instead the workaround is to somehow hold a reference the old file and compare the number of rows to the current file. If there's a discrepancy then will have to compare and extract. Otherwise do nothing.